# How do I get the current tag in underscore templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, data-binding, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a bit of `underscore` html template that looks like this:

```
<% _.each(relations, function(relation) { %>
<tr>
  <td class="center"><%= relation.fromProjectCode %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= relation.toProjectCode %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= relation.userId %></td>
  <td class="center"><div class="label label-<%=tplFns.getLabelClass(relation.status)%>"><%= relation.status %></div></td>
  <td class="center"><%= tplFns.formatDate(relation.requestDate) %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= tplFns.formatDate(relation.acceptDate) %></td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
```

When I am in the `_.each` loop, I want to access the `<tr>` tag and bind some data to it. The problem is that I can write something like this:

```
<tr <% this %> >
```

But here, `this` refers to the current loop object (ie. `relation`) and not the tag.
If there was a way that I could access the current tag, I wanted to bind some data to it like `$(currentTag).data("relation", relation)`. Does anybody know if that is possible?
This is sort of a trivial task and I don't want to add any other libraries to the project for this. So it will be really appreciated if you could tell me of workarounds/solutions with my current set of libraries: `requirejs`, `jquery` and `underscore`

Comment: What is this "requirejs template" thing you are referring to? RequireJS does not innately support templates. You're talking about a plugin for RequireJS, something else, what/

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am talking about. The template plugin that require.js uses. That is not the point thought. Anybody having seen this question should have figured that out. The template plugin comes with require.js you want it or not. So anybody may as well be familiar with it and have used it.

Comment: There is no template plugin that "comes with RequireJS." Here's an (hopefully comprehensive) [list](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Plugins#templating) of the template plugins that exist for RequireJS, and you'll note that **none** of the [official plugins](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Plugins#official-plugins) is for templates. So, again, which one are you using?

Comment: I am really sorry. I owe you an apology. I guess it was so obvious for me because I saw it [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-template) and the backbone docs and the require docs sort of look alike because of the left pane. I am using `underscore` for my templates. I'll just correct the question.